# Solve for $m$ in $(-3m)^2=4p-8$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So, usually when I finish answering a question in my book, I peek at the answers.

It seems like I'm (for me at least) unexplainably incorrect.

The question is to solve $m$ in $(-3m)^2=4p-8$

My working is as follows:

> $$(-3m)^2=4p-8$$
>   $$9m^2=4p-8$$
>   $$m^2=\frac {4p-8}{9}$$
>   $$m=\sqrt\frac{4p-8}{9}$$

But the book states that the answer is $m =-\sqrt\frac{4p-8}{9}$

Why is the answer a negative?

Comment: $m^2=x$ has two solutions, $m=\sqrt{x}$ and $m=-\sqrt{x}$. It looks strange that the exercise starts with $(-3m)^2$, which is $(3m)^2$. Are you sure you have copied it right?

Comment: The answer should be $\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{4p-8}9}=\pm\dfrac23\sqrt{p-2}$ not just the negative part, unless there is a constraint for $m$.

Comment: It is not unlikely that the author wanted to emphasize the fact that there is another answer besides the almost obvious one that you have well calculated

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $$m=\pm\sqrt{\frac{4p-8}{9}}$$ is only true if $$4p-8\geq 0$$ if $m$ is real